# How do I remove these deck railing covers?

Tags: deck, railing

[image: Top view]I have to replace a post cover on my deck because the flag pole the previous owners screwed into it got ripped out in a wind storm. I can’t seem to figure out how the braces that cover where the rails connect to the post are supposed to be removed. Usually they screw in but these don’t have any screws. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Bottom of rail cover]

[image: Rail cover]

Comment: A picture from the top would be helpful as well, but off hand, it looks like they snap on or maybe snap on and then slide down into place.

Comment: Picture of top view added.

Answer (score 1):

Slide them away from the post. They engage with flanges inside and there may be a snapping action. Then the screws will be exposed.

Comment: They don’t move. I’m wondering if they were glued in place.

Comment: Unless someone went off-script, those parts are never glued. It may take a bit of force to overcome the retention.